# Laravel: SQL error when using block of code to set field on customer object

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am getting the following error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'code' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `coupons` (`updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values (2019-12-23 14:06:02, 2019-12-23 14:06:02))

I did some debugging and see it's coming from this following block of code but can't tell why.

```php
if ($customer && is_null($customer->referral_code)) {
    $coupon = new Coupon;
    $coupon->generateReferralCoupon($customer);
    $coupon->save();
    $customer->referral_code = $coupon->code;
    $customer->save();
}
```

The migration to add the `referral_code` is below.

```
class AddReferralInfoToShopUsersTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('shop_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('referral_code')->nullable();
            $table->integer('referral_uses')->nullable();
            $table->integer('referral_revenue')->nullable();
            $table->index(['referral_code']);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post your `generateReferralCoupon()` method to see where the mistake is coming from.

Comment: The error is happening on the `coupons` table. Please provide us the correct migration. You could probably already fix it by doing something like `$table->string('code')->nullable()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the error code it seems you miss assignment to `code` property or you haven't put `code` into fillable array in `Coupon` model.

So quite possible is that instead of:

```
$coupon->generateReferralCoupon($customer);
```

you should use:

```
$coupon->code = $coupon->generateReferralCoupon($customer);
```